# Display drivers stopped responding while playing Guild Wars 2

Tags: pc, guild-wars-2

I have a computer with an Nvidia 660 that is running Windows 10. The game runs perfectly fine for about 10 minutes, and then the display drivers stop responding and they do not recover.

Comment: What version of the drivers are you using?

Comment: If it happens during every game, guaranteed it's your video card going.

Comment: I suggest you to update your video card drivers.
http://www.geforce.com/drivers

Comment: Totally agree with the above. Do a clean install of the latest graphics drivers, and then perhaps do a FurTest or similar on your card to check it's working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to delete and then reinstall the game. If that doesn't help, go through your files and see if there's anything suspicious or something you didn't download. If nothing is out of the ordinary, then I have no clue.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, but if you would like to add a comment, please use the 'add a comment' link below the question.